# sqli error with prepare statement

Tags: php, mysqli

this is my first time using Mysqli and i been stuck on this problem for about an hour now. I am getting this error

```
mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters 
in prepared statement in C:\wamp\www\WebContent\success.php on line 30
```

i have counted like 10 times the questions marks in the prepare statement and there are 21, then i counted the s and the variables in bind_param and there are 21 too. I am new at Mysqli, I was wondering if i can get any suggestion on how to aproach and debug this problem, thank you for all your help

```
<?php   


$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root","","test");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
 }


    $i=0;

 if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `table` SET `Lan_ID` = '?', `Switching` = '?',
   `Own` = '?',`Division` = '?',`Switch_Number` = '?',
   `Telecom_Circuit_number` = '?', `Transmitter_Frequency` = '?',
   `Receiver_Frequency` = '?', `Band_width` = '?', `Channel` = '?', 
   `Equipment` = '?', `Power` = '?', 
   `Line_designation` = '?', `Voltage` = '?', `Phase` = '?',
   `Modulate` = '?', `Terms` = '?', `Trap` = '?',
   `Ltunner` = '?', `Link` = '?', 
   `Comment` = '?' ". $_GET['where'.$i] ))
    {
        $stmt->bind_param('sssssssssssssssssssss', $_GET[$i.'LanID'],$_GET[$i.'Switching'],
        $_GET[$i.'Own'], $_GET[$i.'Division'], $_GET[$i.'Switch_Number'], $_GET[$i.'Telecom_Circuit_number'],
        $_GET[$i.'Trasmitter_frq'], $_GET[$i.'Receiver_frq'], $_GET[$i.'Band_width'], $_GET[$i.'Channel'],
        $_GET[$i.'Equipment'], $_GET[$i.'Power'], $_GET[$i.'Line_designation'],$_GET[$i.'Voltage'],
        $_GET[$i.'Phase'],$_GET[$i.'Modulate'],$_GET[$i.'Terms'], $_GET[$i.'Trap'],$_GET[$i.'Ltunner'],
        $_GET[$i.'Link'], $_GET[$i.'Comment'] );//this is line 30 btw


    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Prepared Statement Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);

    }
    $stmt->close();
 ?>
```

Comment: `$_GET['where'.$i]` smells like sql injection..

Comment: @redreggae the $_GET['where'.$i] is the where clause with all the infromation passed from the last page in order to update a certain column, all of them are dropdown option so i dont think it can happen, correct me if im wrong though because I am new to this topic :)

Comment: yes you are wrong..you cannot trust `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE` vars (among others). These are all easy to manipulate. Try it with [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) or [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/poster/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put parameter placeholders inside quotes.

But that's just the start of your problems.  By interpolating `$_GET['where'.$i]` into your query, you've opened yourself up to SQL injection attacks.  You've completely missed the point of secure programming.

You must not take a WHERE clause, or any expression, verbatim from the HTTP request and copy it into your SQL string.  But you can't use a query parameter for an SQL expression, you can only use a parameter in place of a single scalar value.

Comment: ohhhh, thanks for the advice, I did not know that, this is my first time trying this out, thank you so much, umm, by the way, by saying parameter placeholders you mean the question marks right? sorry if it is a dumb question :/

Comment: thank you so much, i got it to work, I am going to take the $_GET['where'.$i] from there and try to do it another way too, thank you again